# Tikz Library Graph.standard Error: Minimal working example about Tikz Graph library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, bugs

I am trying to get a minimal working example about Tikz Graph library working but unsuccessful. I am getting the examples from the page 298 on the tikz manual [3.0.0-cvs](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.pdf), also the page 299 on the 3.0.1 manual with `texdoc tikz`.

**So how can I get a minimal working example about tikz graph library working?**

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
%Example of p.298 not working
%http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.pdf
\tikz \graph [clockwise, clique] { subgraph I_n [n=4] };
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Graph.standard library not found:** the example is just after the graph.standard library entry but its loading causes err that the lib cannot be found

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in the documentation. This here works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [clockwise, clique] { subgraph I_n [n=4] };
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Correct, also the same bug in the manual 3.0.1 with `texdoc tikz`shows up. The correct line is `\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}` (not graph) +1.

Comment: So make a bug report ...

Comment: Unfortunately no sourcefourge account but encourage people to file it [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/) :)